# Going from positive semi-definiteness to norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-norms

Given two (in my case, real and symmetric) matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $A \succeq B$, I want to check if $\lVert A \rVert \geq \lVert B \rVert$ (for any matrix norm, but in my work I'm using the 2-norm). Here's my work so far:

Since $A - B \succeq 0$, we have, by definition, for some arbitrary $z \in \mathbb{R}^d$, $z^T (A - B) z \geq 0$. By Cauchy-Schwarz, we have

$$\begin{aligned}
\langle z, (A-B)z\rangle &\leq \langle z, z\rangle \cdot \langle (A-B)z, (A-B)z\rangle \\
    &= \lVert z \rVert^2_2 \cdot \lVert (A - B)z \rVert^2_2
\end{aligned}$$

But $z^T (A-B) z \geq 0$ so that $\lVert z \rVert^2_2 \cdot \lVert (A - B)z \rVert^2_2 \geq 0 \Rightarrow \lVert (A - B)z \rVert^2_2 \geq 0$ since $\lVert z \rVert^2_2$ is a non-negative real number. I'm not quite sure where to go from here. What am I missing?

ETA: In my problem, $B = \mu I$, but I'm wondering if there's a general relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the spectral norm is just the largest singular value; since we are working over PSD matrices it is the same as the largest eigenvalue. But the largest eigenvalue of $A$ is larger than the largest eigenvalue of $B$: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2822830/loewner-order-in-terms-of-eigenvalues) for a general answer.